# How to remove extra comma from line in text file in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to remove extra comma from end of the line in text file. Below is my approach:

```
set "n=%~,"
for %%t in (*.txt) do (
findstr /v /r /c:"$[%n%]*$" > res.txt
)
```

But it's no replacing the extra comma from text file. The content of text file as follows:

```
abc,asd,123,
1234,prq,456,,,,,
jkl,abc,9876,,,
5679,3459,gjh,,
```

I want the expected output as follows:

```
abc,asd,123
123,prq,456
jkl,abc,9878
5679,3459,gjh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think substring will help you to get it done:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set txtPath=%%~fa
    echo !txtPath!
    for /f %%b in ('type "!txtPath!"') do (
        set line=%%b
        set output=!line!
        if "!line:~-1!"=="," (
            for /l %%i in (1,1,1000) do if "!output:~-1!"=="," set output=!output:~0,-1!
        )
        echo !output!>> res.txt
    )
)
```

As shown in the code above, It will help to trim up to 1,000 unwanted trailing comma and place the formatted output to a text file. You may refer to this [link](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more information about string manipulation in batch. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for response,I want the output to be in text file

Comment: I have update my question and expected output. And I want to clear myself as I have not mentioned the file name,but you have mentioned the filename can you please provide me approach for that

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to change my old file name I want the output to the same file

Comment: With your approach sometimes the content is getting exactly double in res.txt... kindly help me out

Comment: Did you delete `res.txt` before running it again?

Comment: I am doing that in my code before execution of that batch file completes. One more I would like to mention It is not happening every time it's for random only

Comment: Did you run it on the command line or you click on the batch in GUI manner?

Comment: I think it will be recommended to run it in the command prompt. This will help to prevent the script from running twice :)

Comment: but I need to run the batch file not through the command prompt

Comment: Try to double-click once. It is because if you double-click for multiple times, the batch file will be running twice.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
for %%t in (*.txt) do (
   type "%%t" |repl ",*$" "" >> res.tmp
)
ren res.tmp res.txt
```

Comment: repl is a search and replace tool and it takes the file, removes every comma before the end of the line.  In regular expressions `*` means every character matching the one before the `*` and `$` means the end of the line.  That match is being replaced with a null string `""`  Please ask specific questions if you need more information.

Comment: Why you have used |rep1 in that statement

Comment: It is REPL without a 1 in the name.  That is the helper batch file - did you try it?  It is piping each file through the repl.bat file.